# unable to slide images properly

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5

Iam making a simple website with laravel 5. I need to slide images dynamically but it slide another div instead of images,please help me
my actualy

html code

```
 <section class="clients">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8">
             <p class="clients_head">Alliances</p>
               <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-1 client_img">
                        <img src="images/gic.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/unitedindia.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/avgen.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/oman.png">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-1 client_img">
                        <img src="images/gic.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/unitedindia.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/avgen.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/oman.png">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control arow" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <img src="css/images/arrw-left.png">
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control arow1" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <img src="css/images/arrw-right.png">
                  </a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-1">
              <p class="clients_head">Forex</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3"> 
              <div class="forex">
                <table>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                    <th>Currency</th>
                    <th>Buying</th>
                    <th>Selling</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>EUR</td>
                    <td>95</td>
                    <td>95.95</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>JPY</td>
                    <td>0.8706</td>
                    <td>0.8793</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>AUD</td>
                    <td>72.49</td>
                    <td>73.21</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>CAD</td>
                    <td>70.93</td>
                    <td>71.64</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td colspan="3" class="exchange">For more exchange rate <a href="#" class="link">click here</a></td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>   
              </table>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </section><!--clients end-->
    </div>
```

my view code to make dynamic

```
<section class="clients">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8">
             <p class="clients_head">Alliances</p>
               <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner inner" role="listbox">
                  @if(isset($allinaces))
                       @foreach($allinaces as $alliance)
                       @if(count($alliance)==0)
                    <div class="item active">

                    </div>
                   @else
                    <div class="item">
                    @endif
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <img src="backend/alliances/{{$alliance->image}}">
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                @endforeach
                @endif
                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control arow" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <img src="css/images/arrw-left.png">
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control arow1" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <img src="css/images/arrw-right.png">
                  </a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-1">
              <p class="clients_head">Forex</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3"> 
              <div class="forex">
                <table>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                    <th>Currency</th>
                    <th>Buying</th>
                    <th>Selling</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>EUR</td>
                    <td>95</td>
                    <td>95.95</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>JPY</td>
                    <td>0.8706</td>
                    <td>0.8793</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>AUD</td>
                    <td>72.49</td>
                    <td>73.21</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>CAD</td>
                    <td>70.93</td>
                    <td>71.64</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td colspan="3" class="exchange">For more exchange rate <a href="#" class="link">click here</a></td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>   
              </table>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </section><!--clients end-->
```

I think the error is because iam unable to use @if and @else in proper div. I have spend many hour but unable to solve it ,hope you guys help me.

Comment: do u have demo to show?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there was an error in If else condition. I did some changes in your 
code. Hope it will work.

```
<section class="clients">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8">
             <p class="clients_head">Alliances</p>
               <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner inner" role="listbox">
                  @if(isset($allinaces))
                       @foreach($allinaces as $alliance)
                       @if(count($alliance)==0)
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-1 client_img">
                          <img src="images/gic.png">
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="images/unitedindia.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="images/avgen.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="images/oman.png">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   @else
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="backend/alliances/{{$alliance->image}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="images/unitedindia.png">
                         </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="images/avgen.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                          <img src="images/oman.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endif

                @endforeach
                @endif
                </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control arow" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <img src="css/images/arrw-left.png">
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control arow1" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <img src="css/images/arrw-right.png">
                  </a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-1">
              <p class="clients_head">Forex</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3"> 
              <div class="forex">
                <table>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                    <th>Currency</th>
                    <th>Buying</th>
                    <th>Selling</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>EUR</td>
                    <td>95</td>
                    <td>95.95</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>JPY</td>
                    <td>0.8706</td>
                    <td>0.8793</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>AUD</td>
                    <td>72.49</td>
                    <td>73.21</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>CAD</td>
                    <td>70.93</td>
                    <td>71.64</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td colspan="3" class="exchange">For more exchange rate <a href="#" class="link">click here</a></td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>   
              </table>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </section><!--clients end-->
```

Comment: @Deeepak saini i have not got any images but when i paste <img src="backend/alliances/{{$alliance->image}}"> after endif i got all images from database but they are not sliding.

Comment: You have to give the actual path of the images which is listing from database. This is depends on your code or concept what are you fetching and what to print.

Comment: But it slides only one image at a time. I need to slide at least 4 images at a time